# Create a Megaman like character selection screen with Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, 2d, game-engine

I want to create a character selection screen like the old Megaman games beside that i want to create the menus for the game my question is how do i navigate through game objects using the keyboard or the Dpad and selecting them?

I dont want to use UI elements but box colliders and such can anyone please provide an example how to achieve this?

I followed other Unity tutorials however it uses UI buttons.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

1.Name all your NonUIButtons in ascending order [eg: Button1,Button2,etc.,]
2.Enable the first button on Awake()

```
void Awake(){
currentValue=0;
GameObject goToEnable = GameObject.Find("NonUIButton1");
goToEnable.SetActive(true);
}
```

3.Get the list of allButtons

```
public List<GameObject> items = new List<GameObject>();
void Start(){
items.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("NonUIButtons");}
```

4.When ever key is pressed calcualte the movement using simple additions and subtraction, disable all Buttons and Enable the only one you want

```
void Update(){
if (Input.GetKeyDown("Up"))
{
currentValue  -= 3; // Assuming each row has 3 buttons
foreach(GameObject obj in items){
obj.SetActive(false);
}
}// DO similar steps for each type of movement also make sure to add edge cases

}
```

5. Enabling the Button you want

   GameObject goToEnable = GameObject.Find("NonUIButton1");
   goToEnable.SetActive(true);

Comment: Thank you so much for this very detailed answer.